# CheckBox Angular JS Dúvidas

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Estou com um pequeno empecilho na minha aplicação, tenho uma Grid com check-box e um *check-box para marcar todos*. Quero uma função que **desmarque** o *check-box que marca todos* quando não tiver todos os check-box da grid marcado.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkBox" ng-model="chkMarcaTodos"/></th>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Telefone</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="cad in cadastros track by $index">
            <td><input type="checkBox" ng-model="cad.selecionado"/></td>
            <td>{{cad.nome}}</td>
            <td>{{cad.telefone}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

> Concluindo[...]

Quero que o chkMarcaTodos seja marcado se todos os cad.selecionado estiverem marcado e que o chkMarcaTodos seja desmarcado caso algum cad.selecionado seja desmarcado.

Comment: mostra seu código angular, o que tentou fazer até agora, os valores do ng-repeat para não termos o trabalho de simula-lo novamente...

Comment: @FelipeDuarte independente das informações, aí é só um exemplo, o que preciso pode ser aplicado a qualquer exemplo que haja flags (check-box) e um check box que marca todos. OBS: O que tentei é irrelevante pois não funcionou.